# The most super simple example to start woking with NetHTTP

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, net-http

In Rail my final goal is to write a Net::HTTP client to connect to my REST API that is returning JSON and parse it, pass it to View , etc....
But first things first!
What is the simplest thing I can start with?

I am looking at this page:http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html

and I get the impression that if I have one .rb file with these two lines of code in it, it should show me something?

```
require 'net/http'
Net::HTTP.get('example.com', '/index.html')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
url = URI.parse("http://example.com")
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url.path)
@resp = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port).start {|http| http.request(req)}
```

in a view

```
<%= "The call to example.com returned this: #{@resp}" %>
```

Comment: what's the place to put the nethttp code?  like in a controller?

Comment: Yea, definitely that would be in a controller

Answer (score 1):

You could start testing with something like this:

```
require 'net/http'
response = Net::HTTP.get_response("www.google.com","/")
puts response.body
```

I'll recommend you take a look at the docs: [Net::HTTPSession](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html)